# Multiple form-data with openfeign

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, form-data, openfeign

I try to define multiple params in form-data with spring **openfeign**

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

(version 2.1.9.RELEASE)

here is the method

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
Result test(
    @Param("file") MultipartFile file,
    @Param("contraints") List<String> contraints);
```

but I get the following exception when starting service :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract (org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,java.util.List)
at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:130) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `Feign` and `Spring` annotations will cause the issue.

Make sure you are using `openfeign` library `@Param`, not the spring query `@Param` and it's better to use `@RequestParam` instead of `@param`

For file, it's recommended to use `@RequestPart` instead of `@Param`

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/endpoint"}, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
public Result test(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file);
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
it work if i have the file only but with the second param I have always :
Method has too many Body parameters: